# Are there (interesting) Poincare-invariant QFTs with non-invariant Lagrangian densities?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, poincare-symmetry

In all QFTs I know, the Lagrangian density is completely invariant under the Poincare group,
$$
\mathcal L \to \mathcal L.
$$
On the other hand, the action would be invariant even if the Lagrangian density were invariant only up to a derivative of something, e.g.
$$
\mathcal L \to \mathcal L + \partial_1 K.
$$
(In this case the action is preserved since $\int d^4x \,\,\partial_1 K(x)=0$.)

**Are there any important or interesting QFTs for which the extra term in the Lagrangian density is non-zero, but the action is invariant under the Poincare group?**

Remark: There is a somewhat analogous situation in QFT's with super-symmetry: the super-symmetry transformations preserve the action, but do change the Lagrangian density.

Comment: Such symmetries are known as [quasisymmetries](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451). See also [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14875/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456717/2451) Phys.SE posts.