# Lorentz covariant equation of motion without Lorentz invariant action

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory

The equations of motion of any special relativistic (quantum or classical) field theory must be Lorentz covariant. For this reason, when writing down a Lagrangian (density) it is generally assumed that the Lagrangian must be a Lorentz scalar, since this always generates a Lorentz covariant equation. However, it is possible (c.f. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/do-an-action-and-its-euler-lagrange-equations-have-the-same-symmetries?noredirect=1&lq=1) stack exchange post) for an equation of motion to possess symmetries that its action does not. Is is possible for a Lagrangian that is not a Lorentz scalar to generate a Lorentz covariant equation of motion? If so, are there any prominent examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237302/2451

Comment: That question is in a similar spirit, but my question is definitely different.