# Convert a quasi-symmetry of the action into a strict symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, noethers-theorem

A *quasi-symmetry* of an action $S$ is a transformation of the fields that leaves the action invariant up to a boundary term (see e.g. the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24596/is-the-converse-of-noethers-first-theorem-true-every-conservation-law-has-a-sy)). In contrast, let us call a transformation of the fields that leaves the action invariant without producing a boundary term a *strict symmetry*.
Under which conditions is it possible to convert a quasi-symmetry into a strict symmetry of an action by the addition of boundary terms?

As an example consider the following action:
$$
S=-\frac{1}{2}\int dt \left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)^2 \,.
$$
This action is invariant under the transformation $\delta_{\epsilon}f=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2 f+\epsilon_3 f^2$ up to a boundary term
$$
\delta_\epsilon S=\epsilon_3 \int dt f''(t)\,,$$
so that the transformation is a quasi-symmetry. However, adding the boundary term $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)$ to the action which subsequently reads
$$
S=\int dt \left(\frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}\right)^2\right)$$
the action is invariant under the symmetry without an additional boundary term so that the transformation comprises a strict symmetry.

Under which condition does this work in general?

Comment: Related example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14875/2451