# What is Theorem Schmeorem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, soft-question

It appears in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/14928/74868), but practically nowhere else. Is it a really existing theorem, or is it a joke?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication

Comment: Please explain the -1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about language, not physics.

Comment: I wonder what I should have done if I didn’t know this language turn, so I don’t even know if it’s physics or anything else.

Comment: You might ask about Shm-reduplication in one of the Stack Exchange communities where people talk about language usage.

Comment: @rob If I had known it was an Shm reduplication, I wouldn’t have had to ask anything.:)

Comment: @mma A [possibly-related Meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13342/44126).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [dismissive snowclone](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordSchmord), [sometimes spelled without the *c*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication). This example prefaces a correction with a warning that a purported theorem is incorrect.