# When space expands where do the energy of the gravitational wave dissipate to?

Tags: gravitational-waves, cosmological-inflation, redshift

I think it is safe to say that gravitational wave do not dissipate unless it met matter along the way imparting some of it's energy to cause some distortion or when it's frequency is stretched even longer as space expands like balloon. I think space doesn't dilute so how can the frequency of gravitational wave become stretched?

Comment: Also useful answers at [photons in expanding space: how is energy conserved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/photons-in-expanding-space-how-is-energy-conserved) and [With redshift, energy is lost. Where does it go?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118590/with-redshift-energy-is-lost-where-does-it-go)