# Does a wave blue-shifted by the doppler effect increase in energy?

Tags: energy, waves

A wave is blue-shifted by the doppler effect.

This increases it's frequency, so this should also increase it's energy as per the equation E = hv ?

Therefore does the wave increase in energy from the doppler effect, and if so is it proportionate to the velocity which causes the doppler shift in the first place?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/conservation-of-energy-and-doppler-effect?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,a blue shift increases the energy of a light wave propotionate to the velocity of the observer,but only from the point of view of the observer or whatever object is travelling toward it. This is why particles travelling through space at speeds close to c can materialise photons which would otherwise have insufficient energy for materialisation to take place.