# In empty space what happens to the lights energy that is lost to the doppler effect go to?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, energy-conservation, doppler-effect

When light makes a long distance journey it's frequency shifts toward longer wavelengths.

With $E = hc/\lambda$ being the amount of energy in any given photon (see photon energy); as it travels trough space it wavelength is lengthened which means it's loosing energy as it travels through empty space.

As energy is conserved is it being converted to make more space or is there an interaction with vacuum energy that explains what happens to the energy of the photon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conservation of energy and Doppler effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15279/)

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate, but the short answer is that energy is not conserved in special relativity, but 4-momentum is.

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman Energy is the temporal component of the four-momentum, so conservation of four-momentum implies conservation of energy.

Comment: @G.Smith I believe it's the other way around, individually conserving energy and 3-momentum conserves 4-momentum, but 3-momentum certainly isn't conserved in Lorentz transformations, since for massive objects at least, you can always boost to a frame where the momentum is zero. Similarly, in the rest frame, the energy is equal to the rest energy, but this isn't true for other inertial frames.

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman You are confusing conservation/non-conservation and invariance/non-invariance. They are unrelated concepts.

Comment: @G.Smith yes, I guess that's true

Comment: Thank you for the reading material, is it possible to add a consistent frame of reference to his problem?