# How does speed of a thermodynamic process determine its type(adiabatic or isothermal)?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, work, adiabatic

The part explaining adiabatic process in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/8548/314853) answer says that,

> In reality, adiabatic processes are approximations. They work best with systems that are almost isolated, but have a limited way of interacting with the environment, or else occur too quickly for interactions beside pressure-volume ones to be important.

**"or else occur too quickly for interactions beside pressure-volume ones to be important."** I am having trouble understanding this concept relating time of transfer of heat. *If heat change does take place, howsoever quickly with the outside environment, it is still non zero right?*

I have a similar problem regarding isothermal processes as well, about which I have read in a book that heat transfer occurs slowly. If heat transfer in a long time is $dQ$ then $dQ=nCdT$, but after a long long time won't temperature change be non zero(essentially integrating both sides)?

How does *how quickly or how slowly* a process takes place determine the type of thermodynamic process(adiabatic or isothermal)?

Comment: These are all approximations. In the limit of 0 time or infinite time you’ll get those two processes and anything in practice will be modeled perfectly by neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does how quickly or how slowly a process takes place determine the
> type of thermodynamic process(adiabatic or isothermal)?

The amount of heat that is transferred is the integral of the  heat transfer rate over time.  If some portion of a process occurs quickly (i.e., in approximately zero time) the amount of heat transfer becomes zero. That portion of the process can be considered adiabatic. However, given time and an opportunity for the system to re-equilibriate with its surroundings, heat transfer can occur.

As an example, consider an ideal gas in a vertically oriented cylinder fitted with a frictionless piston in a constant temperature environment. On top of the piston is a bag of sand. Initially the internal and external pressures are the same, i.e., $P_{gas}=P_{ext}$. The entire bag of sand is abruptly removed from the piston. The external pressure is therefore abruptly reduced to atmospheric pressure, as shown in FIG 1 below, such that there was no time for heat to transfer to the gas, i.e., that portion of the process is adiabatic. However, after the transition the gas is allowed to expand irreversibly against constant external pressure transferring heat from the surroundings and doing work, until the gas pressure and temperature re-equilibriates with the surroundings (state 2). Since the final gas temperature equals the initial gas temperature (before removing he weight), the change in internal energy is zero (for an ideal gas).  The net work done (area under the constant external pressure process) equals the heat added to the gas.

Instead of removing the entire bag of sand,  we now reduce the external pressure infinitely slowly (quasi statically) by removing one grain of sand at a time, so that the gas pressure never varies significantly from the external pressure. With each removal of grain of sand the infinitesimal decrease in external gas pressure results in an infinitesimal expansion (infinitesimal amount of work) and an infinitesimal decrease in temperature. This results in an infinitesimal transfer of heat from the surroundings to the gas restoring its temperature to the initial temperature (temperature of the surroundings). The process is continued until the entire bag of sand is removed and the pressure becomes atmospheric. The result is a reversible isothermal (constant temperature) expansion. A PV diagram of the process is shown in FIG 2 below. The area under the curve is the net work done by the gas.

Comparing the two figures we find more work is done in FIG 2 than FIG 1 because heat was added to the gas during the entire expansion process in FIG 2, whereas in FIG 1 heat was only added during the constant external pressure process.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: So, when each grain of sand is removed, the infinitesimal temperature drop is compensated for with an infinitesimal temperature rise from the surroundings by adding an infinitesimal amount of heat to the gas in the piston as it happens very slowly, hence its isothermal, but when the bag of sand is abruptly removed, the temperature drops by a great amount abruptly in a short time(NOT DUE TO HEAT TRANSFERRING OUT OF THE GAS BUT BECAUSE OF THE GAS DOING WORK ON THE PISTON), not giving chance for heat to externally enter the system, hence its adiabatic.

Is that right?

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent "but when the bag of sand is abruptly removed, the temperature drops by a great amount abruptly in a short time" The temperature and pressure WITHIN the gas does not drop abruptly. There's not enough time. The temperature and pressure only at the boundary (interface) between the gas and surroundings are the same.  But when the gas expands rapidly at constant external pressure, the pressure and temperature within the gas drop rapidly (irreversibly) unlike when the gas expands slowly when one grain of sand at a time is removed, until eventually equilibrium is re-established.

Comment: Oh I see, so the volume of gas inside the piston increases at constant external pressure, while the gas pressure decreases, and this happens so rapidly that temperature drops faster than it can be replenished by the outside temperature by feeding heat to it while its expanding. Is that right then?

Comment: @AltercatingCurrent Essentially correct, at least when it initially expands against constant external pressure. But eventually heat transfers to the gas so that it comes into equilibrium with the surroundings at state 2 in Fig 1

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

All real matter conducts heat, and even in a vacuum there is thermal energy exchange via radiation. So if you wait long enough nothing is *thermally* isolated but empirically, say an audio frequency power transistor sitting on a heat spreader plate could be considered an adiabatic system because the rate its temperature internally changes is related to the rate with which it is driven between the lowest and highest audio frequencies of interest, say 20Hz to 20kHz. Even the lowest 20Hz rate, or 50msec "characteristic time", of the fluctuation rate is much slower than  anything that could affect its temperature from the *outside*, hence it could be considered an adiabatic system at these time scales. Of course, it is not really adiabatic because as the plate temperature increases or decreases with the that of the environment the overall behavior of the transistor changes as well, but not on millisecond time scales.

A similar situation you can have  with a car battery whose behavior is very strongly dependent on its environmental temperature. Given that if you nearly short circuit with huge current load, starting the engine several times in cold or hot weather the amount of charge it can deliver in a current surge depends on that outside temperature but not details of it from which it is practically adiabatically isolated for that short surge time.