# Total work done by friction on a system, when friction is static and internal to system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, work, friction, relative-motion

Will the total work done by friction on a system be always zero if friction is static and internal to the system? Explain if possible by man boat problem as system and no friction is being provided by water to boat.  Friction only exists between man and boat and man is walking without skidding to the other end.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but know that static friction can never do any work as an internal force.

Comment: @ Sam... Why? Can you explain a bit more. I can't find the underlying logic,  everone is stating it as a fact like you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What will be the total work done by friction on the system (man+boat)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520756/)

Comment: And if  not, why not?

Answer (score -1):

The man and the boat represent an isolated system. When the man walks on the boat, the frictional force also acts on the boat as a reaction force. Since the action AND reaction happen together at the same place, there can be no net work done.