# Work and Area under a Curve relating to Hooke's Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, newtonian-mechanics, spring, work

> If it takes work W to stretch a Hooke’s-law spring (F = kx) a distance d from its unstressed length, determine the extra work required to stretch it an additional distance d (Hint: draw a graph and give answer in terms of W!).

I don't understand why the answer is not 2W since Force is proportional to x, or even how to begin using a graph to disprove why the answer is not 2W. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -1 You could not draw a graph of $F$ vs $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without a graph, the answer is straightforward. The potential energy stored in a spring is proportional to the square of the difference b/w stretched and unstretched length,

$$V = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 $$

Thus, the work required to stretch it (mind you, you have to do this slowly so that the Kinetic Energy isn't changed) would be:

$$W = \frac{1}{2}k(2d)^2 - \frac{1}{2}k(d)^2 = \frac{3}{2}kd^2 = 3W_0$$

This is just straightforward conservation of energy.

Comment: Ah, how did I miss something so easy?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe You might also want to see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-quadratically-not-linearly-with-velocity)