# Why does work equal force times distance?

Tags: forces, kinematics, work

My book says:

> Energy is the capacity to do work and work is the product of net force and the 1-dimensional distance it made a body travel while constantly affecting it.

This seems quite unmotivated to me.

*Why* does [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29) equal $F \cdot d$ ?

Where does the distance part come from?

I always thought of time as the one thing we can only measure (not affect) so it justifies why we may measure other things in relation to time. But we have a much greater control over distance (since it's just a term for a physical dimension we can more or less influence as opposed to time).

**Edit**: That^ doesn't make much sense, but it's been graciously addressed in some of the answers.

*Level:* High-school Physics.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-quadratically-not-linearly-with-velocity/14752#14752 for a better understanding--- the elementary books are uniformly terrible regarding this, and I would recommend to you to throw this book away, and get a better one. The reason it's force time distance is explained using little ramps and elevators, so that you balance the force here with the force there.

Comment: @RonMaimon Your approach is that kinetic energy is proportional to squared velocity and you calculate the expression for work from there.  This is, as you know, quite opposite to standard procedures in elementary books.  Did you choose such procedure because it is *easier*, or do you think one *cannot* properly show that work is force times distance?

Comment: @Pygmalion: I did both--- there is a non-relativistic Galilean motivation for energy is v^2, but there is also an argument for why "force times distance" is the correct definition of work. You put the objects on ramps, and make a pully system to move other objects. If the force-times-distance matches, you can move the objects with the pullies while doing no work (colloquially and physics-wise, the two notions coincide).

Comment: @RonMaimon Could you direct me to your ramp-pully system explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: @Pygmalion: I put a brief version up, but it's Feynman's, really Archimedes'.

Comment: Closely related question that came up later: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310104/why-does-a-force-not-do-any-work-if-its-perpendicular-to-the-motion

Comment: actually, @knzhou, i wonder if that one should be closed in favor of this one

Comment: This question is older than both others... And has more detailed answers. A bit surprising of a reaction, to say the least.

Answer (score 15):

Fortunately, we've equipped ourselves with rulers in addition to clocks, so it's quite possible to measure time *and* distance, and quite useful to do both. Let's push something (with a force $F$ ) so that its velocity changes by $\Delta v$ and figure out how much its energy changes. Say our object is initially moving at speed $v_0$ and has energy 
$$E_0 = \frac{1}{2} m v_0^2$$
After the push, it is moving at $v = v_0 + \Delta v$ so its energy will be:
$$E = \frac{1}{2} m (v_0 + \Delta v)^2$$
$$E = \frac{1}{2}m(v_0^2 + 2v_0\Delta v + \Delta v^2)$$
$$E = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + m v_0\Delta v + \frac{1}{2}m\Delta v^2$$
Now with $\Delta v$ small enough so that we can ignore the last term with $\Delta v ^2$:
$$E = E_0 + mv_0\Delta v$$ or in terms of the change in energy:
$$\Delta E = m v \Delta v$$
There are a few different ways to proceed from here, one is to multiply by $\Delta t / \Delta t = 1$ and rewrite as:
$$ \Delta E = m \left( \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} \right) (\Delta t) \cdot v$$
Now recognizing from Newton's 2nd law that 
$$\frac{m \Delta v}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta (mv)}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t} = F$$
We have that
$$\Delta E = F \Delta t \cdot v$$ but 
$\Delta t \cdot v = \Delta t \left( \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} \right) = \Delta x$ is just how far we pushed it, so
$$ \Delta E = F \cdot \Delta x$$

Thinking about the problem as time progresses, it is natural to also ask *"How fast is the energy changing?"* The answer is that we are supplying [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29) to the system at the rate:
$$ P = \frac{\Delta E}{\Delta t} = F v$$
This may be closer to how you are thinking of it, but as you can see above, if you want to relate the applied force to the change in energy, multiplying the force by the distance over which it is applied gives the correct result.

Comment: Sorry if this is more (or less) mathematics than you were looking for in an answer. Let me know here in the comments if there is anything that is unclear. I hope this helps!

Comment: You should never have to apologize for math ;-) Nice answer.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Thanks for the feedback. I just wasn't sure how to interpret "Level: US Grade-10 equivalent"

Comment: I commend you for the answer, but the argument is usually the opposite.  You start with the definition of the work and from this definition you obtain the kinetic energy.  After all, why would kinetic energy be proportional to the square of velocity?

Comment: @Pygmalion it's true the intro development usually postulates a definition of work and then derives work-energy. For me this is a bit unnatural as energy seems more fundamental. You can start from much more basic assumptions to get E quadratic in v (e.g. symmetry and clay balls here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-quadratically-not-linearly-with-velocity/14752#14752 ). Also, postulating work is clearly not going to answer the question as I read it.

Comment: @tmac OK, I do understand yours and Ron's argument.  I just wonder do you propose some bigger picture too, e.g. are elementary books on physics wrong or awkward?  I am open to other suggestions, as a lecturer I am not myself satisfied with the explanation of the work.  I also lecture my modified explanation, but I still start from the work itself.

Comment: @Pygmalion nothing so grandiose as that, I just think that the more useful perspectives/interpretations you can bring, the more likely you are to help develop understanding.

Comment: @Pygmalion: The elementary physics books are just incompetent. They are repeating things that are found in previous books, and so on like a game of telephone that ends somewhere in the 19th century. The argument about "force times distance" is derived from Archimedes law of the lever, and there is a nice explanation of the same idea in Feynman volume 1. When you have two equal forces, you can move an object down by letting one force act, if you move a second object up by letting the other force act. If the force times distance is equal, you can do this reversibly, without speeding anything up.

Comment: So that's the mathematical argument depending on a presumption that I understand KE! It's still useful though; I don't see that many 'connection-explanations' for physics in the mathematical sense. I can see this helping me sometime in a suitable-level [word-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics_education)). And @tmac, by US G-10 I meant around 17 y.o. in 1st year secondary school. Pathetic, I know!

Comment: @RonMaimon OK, I'll check Feynman 1

Comment: @M.Na'el I know what you meant, I was just saying that it doesn't help that much in terms of your background because of the large variances in education. Nothing pathetic about it! This is a good fundamental question, hopefully these answers help.

Comment: @tmac, And _I_ meant pathetic about the age/school-year combination. Never mind it. Anyway, I mostly meant 'no-calculus' with any other assumptions probably correct too (curricula aren't that varied) but it's because calculus appears to be (and I'm sure, is) a central part in explaining physics; but I have little experience in it.

Comment: @M.Na'el out of curiosity, are you comfortable with the math I presented in my answer? If so, it might be nice to realize it is essentially just a bunch of (admittedly informal) calculus. Calculus (or any mathematical framework) doesn't explain physics, it is an operational tool used to do physics. I think you'll find that developing your understanding of one will help with the other, so if you're learning physics you are developing intuition that will probably be useful for learning calculus.

Answer (score 9):

To add to orbifold's answer, I'll give a quick repeat of Feynman's version of the conservation of energy argument. This is "d'Alembert's principle" or "the principle of virtual work", and it generalizes to define thermodynamic potentials as well, which include entropy quantities inside.

Suppose you have a bunch of masses on the Earth's surface. Suppose you also have some elevators, and pullies. You are asked to lift some masses and lower other masses, but you are very weak, and you can't lift any of them at all, you can just slide them around (the ground is slippery), put them on elevators, and take them off at different heights.

You can put two equal masses on opposite sides of a pulley-elevator system, and then, so long as you lift a mass up by a height h, and lower an equal mass down by an equal height h, you don't need to do any work (colloquially), you just have to give little nudges to get the thing to stop and start at the appropriate height.

If you want to move an object which is twice as heavy, you can use a force doubling machine, like a lever with one arm twice as long as another. By arranging the heavy mass on the short arm, and the light mass on the long arm, you can move the heavy mass down, and the light mass up twice as much without doing any work.

In both these processes, the total mass-times-height is conserved. If you keep the mass-times-height constant at the beginning and at the end, you can always arrange a pulley system to move objects from the initial arrangement to the final one.

Suppose now that the gravitational field is varying, so that some places, you have a strong "g" and other places a weak "g". This requires balancing the total *force* on opposite sides of the elevator, not the total mass. So the general condition that you can move things without effort is that if you move an object which feels a force "F" an amount "d" in the direction of the force is acting, you can use this motion plus a pulley system to move another object which feels a force "F'" an amount "d'" *against* the direction of the force.

This means that for any reversible motion with pullies, levers, and gears

$$\sum_i F_i \cdot d_i = 0 $$

This is the condition under which you don't have to do colloquial work to rearrange the objects. One can take the conserved quantity for these motions to be the sum of the force times the distance for each little motion, and it is additive among different objects, and so long as nothing is moving very fast, if you add up the changes in F dot d for all the objects, it must be zero if you did everything reversibly.

This generalizes to a dynamical situation by adding a quantity of motion which is additively conserved along with F dot d, this quantity is the kinetic energy. You can also go backwards, and start with the kinetic energy idea (which can be motivated by collisions), and re-derive the F dot d thing. These are two complementary points of view that fit together to give a coherent picture of kinetic and potential energy.

if you have a static force field on a particle which has the property that along some closed cycle the sum of the force times the little displacements is not zero, then you can use this cycle to lift weights.

The proof is simple: arrange a pulley system to lift/lower weights at every point along the cycle in such a way that the F dot d of the weights balances the F dot d of the force. Then take the particle around the loop in the direction where F dot d is net positive, while balancing out the force with the weights. At the end of the day, you lifted some weights and brought the particle back where it started.

This means that a non-conservative force can be used to lift a weight. As you traverse the loop, something must be eaten up out of the non-conservative force field, otherwise it is an inexhaustible source of weight-lifting, and violates the first law of thermodynamics. So eventually, all force fields settle down so that the integral of F dot d is zero along every loop. This is the definition of a conservative force.

Comment: Isn't that actually special case of d'Alembert's principle?

Comment: @Pygmalion: Yes, I was trying to remember that guy's name while writing this! Thanks.

Comment: Of course Feynman's explanation assume a homogenous gravitational field.  Work is more general than that.  It *seems* to me that the only general way to introduce the work is by defining scalar field, which *negative* gradient results in force field - that is actually the energy.  Of course, inverse of *negative* gradient is *negative* curve integral and work is *positive* curve integral.  I guess I'd lost my students about the time I mentioned scalar field...

Comment: Actually, @Pygmalion, you lost me at 'homogeneous gravitational field', I never thought there were none uniform fields.

Comment: @RonM, So according to this example, should I see that work is 'how much a force exhausts of an object's potential energy'? Turning it to kinetic or otherwise?

Comment: @M.Na'el: Work is the _change in potential energy_, turning it to kinetic energy or otherwise. If by "exhausts" you mean "exhausts the change", then yes.

Comment: @Pygmalion: As far as homogenous field, no it doesn't. Feynman uses this assumption for simplicity, but it is trivial to generalize the argument, this is what I did in the answer above. In my experience, students do not get confused if you say something advanced, they get confused when you say something wrong or if you don't define your terms in terms of more basic terms. The discussion we are having is understandable by a high school student (we have one here), it is not too advanced.

Comment: @M.Na'el I think our discussion is about the context and possibly perspective.  My experience is that graduate engineering courses are not capable of complex physical reasoning.  Maybe this is true only for graduate students at university I work at.  I also *guess* that writers of the books *share* my view about graduate students' abilities.  But, then, it is *really* the problem of context and perspective.

Comment: @Pygmalion: The problem is that the book writers are incompetent at explaining because they don't understand the material. It has nothing to do with the student's level, this is at bare-bones basics, levers and elevators. There is nobody of sound mind that cannot understand Feynman's argument if properly presented, including an average 10 year old.

Answer (score 7):

You should regard this passage as a perhaps ill motivated definition of what work is for the purpose of your physics course. Let me make some remarks on energy though, since the passage "Energy is the capacity to do work" is misleading at best. There is a law or principle, called *conservation of energy* governing all natural phenomena we are aware of. According to this law there is a quantity called *energy* that does not change during any changes that nature undergoes. It is not tied to anything concrete like pushing boxes around, instead it is an abstract concept.

There are different forms of energy, among them:
gravitational energy, kinetic energy, radiant energy, nuclear energy, mass energy, chemical energy, heat energy, elastic energy, electrical energy.
Notice that those are just other names though, no one really knows what energy *is*, there are just different ways of calculating contributions to it.

For a given physical system the different forms of energies can sometimes be given by concrete formulas. But it is important to realize that conservation of energy is independent of that knowledge. As time goes on, the different forms of energy are converted into each other, conservation of energy means that their sum remains constant.

Now in general energy that is measured relative to the location of something else is called *potential energy*. Examples are the gravitational potential energy or the electric potential energy. How do you change the potential energy of an object? By moving it around. So how does force come into play? Well it turns out that as a general principle:

$$ \{ \text{Change in potential energy} \} = \textrm{(force)} \times (\text{distance force acts through})$$

The reason for this formula is rather simple, if $V$ denotes the potential energy, you can compare it at two neighbouring points $P$ and $P + \delta P$, then *per definition* the infitesimal (that means that you neglect terms with $\delta P^2$) change of the potential is:

$$\delta V = V(P + \delta P) - V(P) = F \cdot \delta P$$

Now you just have to sum up those contributions. To give you a simple example: Take the potential energy $V(x) = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$, then

$$V(x + \delta x) - V(x) = \frac{1}{2} k (2 x \delta x + \delta x^2) = kx\delta x$$

So the force is $F = kx$, which you might recognize as Hooke's law.

If you want to read a much better description of this you should read chapter 4 in Volume 1 of Feynman's Lectures on Physics. Maybe you can get a copy of them in your local library.

Comment: +1 for Feynman 1, he does it right, and he is almost the only one who does it right at the know-nothing level. Landau also does it right, but at a higher level.

Comment: I don't think I'd ever struggled with the idea of a universally constant amount of energy. To me, heat is probably the most basic of all of its faces (since it's one of the bi-bang's prime outputs). It's the representation, though, that troubles me: Why force and distance? I'm getting an idea formed up from all of your answers so you're helping -hopefully- a future scientist!

Comment: One question: Is $\delta V = \text d V$ ?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you mean by $dV$. Indeed in standard mathematical notation, $dV = \partial_x V dx +  \partial_y V dy + \partial_z V dz$ and physicists like to write this as $dV = \vec F \cdot d \vec r$. In words: The infinitesimal change in potential energy is the Force times the infinitesimal change in  position. If you like that is the *definition* of a force. That definition might not be compatible with what you learned in your physics course. But it is the right definition for *conservative* forces. Non conservative forces like friction are a bit trickier.

Comment: So the answer to why force and distance is: You want to keep track of the change in potential energy. Infitesimally that change is determined by definition by $\vec F \cdot d\vec r$, now as you move along a path, you have to sum up (or integrate) those small contributions to get the total change in potential energy. Only in very simple circumstances the end result will literally be simply force times distance.

Comment: @orbifold: The integration is not what is confusing about this--- students understand the integration intuitively. The issue is multiplying "force" (which is a unit of flow of momentum in _time_) by "distance" (which is not related to the definition of force). Why the heck do you get something sensible when you do this? To leave this unmotivated is a major barrier that keeps people from learning.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Well, ok but what is Force? Mathematically it is a one form, you tell me what direction you want to move in and I tell you what force you are experiencing. In standard physics courses forces are of course drawn as vectors, but if you think about it, the direction of the force and the magnitude are really separate. What actually happens is: You or something else decides on a direction and then you get back the magnitude of force in that direction. One forms are naturally integrated along paths.

Comment: @RonMaimon "students understand the integration intuitively".  You're lucky, Ron.  I wish *my* undergraduate students understand integration *any* way, intuitively or not.

Comment: @orbifold: I think of force as a vector, not a one form, although both formulations are identical in Euclidean space. You can think of force as dp/dt, making p is a one form as it is naturally in the Hamiltonian way, or as the integral of a stress-tensor, which makes it more naturally a vector. The issue is that force is only important over distance when there is a machine available that will take that force acting (slowly) over that distance and move that somewhere else to lift some weight an equivalent distance/weight amount. This is the argument that justifies the definition of work.

Comment: @RonMaimon, Why do we multiply Force and Distance to get something useful called Work? What you said is _exactly_ my question.

Comment: @Pygmalion, "I wish my undergraduates understood integration any way, int..." You lost me here; what integration do you mean? Isn't it $(\int \, \text{something_here})$ ?

Comment: @M.Na'el: the reason is that you can put a sliding wall which holds the particle back against the force, and let the force slowly slide the wall, moving a system of pullies that lift a mass somewhere else. The maximum amount of lifting power you get is equal to the force times distance the wall slides, because this is how much the sliding wall can move a weight far away.

Comment: @RonM, That's how I saw it -more or less- in your answer but I was just backing up your claim here fearing it wasn't obvious from my question.

Comment: @M.Na'el: Your question was obvious--- don't get stressed--- you are stepping on educational toes, since the books all explain this incompetently, and people don't like incompetence exposed. Feynman is not used in education because it is too good, educators get embarassed by having lucid arguments about elementary stuff, because they are deluded that they understand the elementary stuff, when usually they don't have any clue. They just learned it by rote or authority. If you understood why, perhaps you can explain it more clearly than anyone else here, because we all learned it decades ago.

Comment: @M.Na'el Exatly.  You'd be surprised how many students have no knowledge of integration.

Comment: @M.Na'el: Pygmalion just means that if the force is changing at different places, you cut up the path into little bits where the force is effectively constant, and take the sum of the little bits. This is called integration. It's not deep, nor is it the confusing thing in this whole business.

Comment: @orbifold I know that's late but... I now feel I was somewhat dense. When you started by stating that energy is abstract and that potential energy (in relation to gravity) is just one form, then stated how we got work from change in potential energy, did you want to convey that it (Work) is a generalization (to all forms of energy) based on this quite simple instance (of potential energy)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the definition of the work is that **our *intuitive* idea of work is simply wrong**.  Imagine for example, that you hold 10 kg box 1 m above the ground for an hour.  You'd probably feel very tired and you'd think "what a work I've done".  But you could easily put the box on a table, that is 1 m high.  The effect on the box would be just the same.  But did the table made any work?  Of course not.  Since table at rest does not have energy (capacity to do work), it could not possibly make any work.  So you see, there is absolutely no direct correspondence between work and time.

An object therefore *must* be moved to actually make a mechanical work.  And even in this case you can move object and still make no work.  Imagine that you are carrying 10 kg box at the height of 1 m from one side of the room to the other side.  It actually requires making some effort to do that.  But you could put the box on the cart 1 m high and just gently and slowly push it over the room.  But did the cart made any work?  The answer is again negative.  Since cart practically at rest does not have energy (capacity to do work), it could not possibly make any work.

Only the product of force and displacement in the direction of the force is a meaningful work.

Comment: Why isn't it the product of force times distance to the 2.3 power?

Comment: @RonMaimon OK, I need lever to explain that.

Comment: @RonMaimon Sleeping over the problem, there is no problem to show that work must be linear in displacement.  You simply halve the displacement and get half the work.  The problem is to show that work is linear in force.  That is why I need a lever.

Comment: Why should half the displacement be half the work? It isn't true in time--- when a constant force is acting, twice the time doesn't make twice the work. You still need a lever to show this, because you need the motion adiabatic, so that equal increments of distance are additive lifting of some weight. You won't make a good argument when you already know the answer, it's best if you don't know anything, that's why old literature is useful, they didn't know anything. By the way, I should have meant (force times distance) to the 2.3 power, any other combination is not rotationally invariant.

Comment: If you argue that it's "force times distance" because you need to integrate for an inhomogenous force, consider Force times velocity to the 2.3 power times dt, which is (F v^1.3) dx. You need to argue that it isn't this combination, or some other one that gives the invariant change in energy.

Comment: @RonMaimon Perhaps... I'll take a peek into Feynman's and perhaps test its arguments on the next generation.  We'll see how students are able to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

It's by moving something over a distance that you put energy into it. You can push a wall with all your strength for hours, but if it doesn't move then it hasn't gained any energy. (Instead your energy will have gone into heating up your body and heating the environment around you)

On the other hand if you carry a weight upstairs, then you are applying a force to it and moving it, and the higher you carry it the more energy the weight has and the more work you could make it do by dropping it.

Comment: This is not an argument.