# How to understand the process of the kinetic energy formula?

Tags: energy, velocity

$$\frac{1}{2} mv^2 = K.E.$$
What is the purpose of $v^2$; why can't use $v$ instead?

Why this question is arising because of that I learned the whole process of speed= distance/time. (I know How it works)
Velocity = displacement/time.
Acceleration,
Average speed,
This whole formula have some connection, that I learned or realised by questioning the formula. But I can't understand $\frac{1}{2} mv^2$.
Without memorizing I want to understand each part of the formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is velocity squared in kinetic energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/379314/)

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* user647077!  This question has been asked and answered here several times. Have you taken the time to search this site for find the answer to your question?  If so, would you edit your question to include what precisely remains unclear after perusing those answers?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488000/207828)

Answer (score 1):

To simply put, Kinetic energy can be calculated by the basic process of computing the work (W) that is done by a force (F). If the body has a mass of m that was pushed for a distance of d on a surface with a force that’s parallel to it.

$W=F.d=m.a.d$

The acceleration in this equation can be substituted by the initial $(v_i)$ and final $(v_f)$ velocity and the distance. This we get from the kinematic equations of motion.

$W=m.a.d\\ \\ =m.d.\frac{v_{f}^{2}-v_{i}^{2}}{2d}\\ \\ =m.\frac{v_{f}^{2}-v_{i}^{2}}{2d}\\ \\ =\frac{1}{2}.m.v_{f}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}.m.v_{i}^{2}$

The Kinetic Energy’s (K) basic quantity $\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$ changes when a particular sum of work is acted upon an object.

$K.E=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$

The total work that is done on a system is equivalent to the change in kinetic energy. Thus,

$W_{net}=\Delta K$

Comment: As a general rule please do not add new answers when duplicate (or almost duplicate) questions exist.  Also note that sometimes these questions fall under the homework-type question policy and insufficient prior research (including e.g. Wikipedia and a search for prior answers) by OPs can be a reason for closing.

Comment: I din't know it initially that it was duplicate. Though I will take care from next time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question has the roots in the symmetry properties of space and time. I will choose the lagrangian formalism of classical mechanics to answer the question, where the lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ is a scalar function which is the difference between kinetic energy and potential energy.

We know that space is homogeneous and isotropic, and time is homogeneous. 
For a free particle, it follows that the lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ should have the following properties:

1. $\mathcal{L}$ should not depend on the position coordinate.
2. $\mathcal{L}$ should not depend on the velocity vector. Rather it should depend on the magnitude of the velocity, i.e., some power of the velocity vector.
3. $\mathcal{L}$ should not depend on the time coordinate.

So the general form of the lagrangian would be $$\mathcal{L}(x,v,t)=\alpha v^n$$ where $\alpha$ is a constant. Now, we can evaluate the momentum by using the relation $$p=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v}=\alpha nv^{n-1}$$
We know that the momentum is a linear function of the velocity. This is possible only when $n=2$ in the above expression.

The lagrangian function is written as $\mathcal{L}=T-U$, where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is the potential energy. Since we are considering a free particle (which has only kinetic energy), the lagrangian (choosing $n=2$) is $$\mathcal{L}=T=\alpha v^2$$
Thus, the kinetic energy is proportional to $v^2$ and not any other power of $v$.