# How - The force of a 60 mph crash is not just twice as great as a 30 mph crash; it’s four times as great!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, collision

The DMV manual says that

> *The faster you go, the less time you
>   have to avoid a hazard or collision.
>   The force of a 60 mph crash is not
>   just twice as great as a 30 mph crash;
>   it’s four times as great!*

My physics is quite rusty, so I could not figure it out. I guess the above statement is correct, but how do we prove it?

**Edit**

I figured this out myself, but alternative methods or new ways of understanding are still welcome.

Comment: I think this can be answered by the basic equations of linear motion. But I can't post my answer till 8 hours...so silly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations

Comment: What is the negative vote for ?

I thought about it again. I think this could be the solution: 

    F = ma, 
    v^2 = u^2 + 2aS

. v = 0 and S = "S1" for both cases.

so, a = -u^2/2s
.let F1 be the force for car traveling at 60mph

F1/F2 = (U1)^2/(U2)^2 = (60/30)^2 = 4,

F1 = 4F2,

Proved....makes sense ?

Comment: Just so you know, inflammatory or offensive posts are not acceptable here

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/2451

Comment: @Jim - ok. But, don't you think there is too much unnecessary down voting going on ?

Comment: While I didn't downvote you, I cannot claim to be omniscient and therefore cannot comment on whether or not the downvoting was unnecessary.

Comment: so much condescension going down all over this question; what site am i on

Comment: This question (v4) should in principle be closed as _too localized._ However, I think, it is more helpful to close it as a _duplicate,_ even if it is strictly speaking not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty basic physics:
We know the following formulae

$$F=ma$$
$$a={v_f^2-v_i^2\over2\Delta d}$$
In both cases, the final velocity is $0$. Assuming you have the same room, $\Delta d$, to decelerate in a crash,

$$F=m{v^2\over2\Delta d}$$

Due to the square of the velocity, if you increase the impact speed by a factor of 2, you increase the impact force by a factor of 4.

Comment: Thanks, I already did it. Stupid SO wont let me post my own answer here.

Comment: please give me an upvote. Some crazy ppl just downvoted me.

Comment: @Useyourhead you're new, so here's some free advice. Asking for upvotes is the only sure way of not getting them.

Comment: This, of course, has the built in assumption that $\Delta d$ is the same in both cases which is generally not true. It is more correct to say that there is four time the mechanical energy and leave it at that.

Comment: @dmckee I agree, but the quoted DMV book said 4 times the force, so I attempted to provide their reasoning. I also did state explicitly that I assumed $\Delta d$ was the same in both cases.