# Intuitive physical concept for squared velocity in the context of energy

Tags: energy

Kinetic energy  $E_{kin} =  \frac{1}{ 2} m v^2 $ may be expressed in $kg \frac{ m^2 }{sec^2}$.The formula includes squared velocity. However, instead of ***squared velocity = v • v***  it seems to be easier to imagine ***acceleration times distance = a • s*** as shown by the formula for work:

***W = F • s = m • a • s***

That means :

- 1. Energy is a constant force ***F*** applied over a distance ***s***, force being mass times acceleration.
- 2. The unit $\frac{ m^2 }{sec^2}$ is divided into $\frac{ m}{sec^2}$ (acceleration) and $m$ (distance) .

I am looking for an intuitive model for the fact that energy includes squared velocity and where **a • s** is replaced by **v • v**.

Does there exist such an intuitive model in any domain of physics?

Comment: The kinetic energy formula is the result of an integration of $dW=Fds$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Derivation

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I thik it verges on the impossibile to think intuitively about nonlinear relationships, that is why we define the energy in terms of force and distance and not in velocity squared. I think the human brain is not made for nonlinear relationships. One of the coolest examples is: guess how many ancestors you had that lived fivehundret years ago, then estimate it in a calculation, you will be surprised, because you just can't think nonlinearly on an intuitive level. But i might be wrong.^^

Answer (score 1):

It is not matter of units, or easier. The issue that you ask implies the energy conservation law:

**if you invest mechanical work you obtain an increase of energy**.

If the effect of the force is that the velocity of an object increases, then the mechanical work was spent for increasing the kinetic energy of the object.

So, imagine a force $F$ pushing an object of mass $m$ along a distance $s$. The mechanical work done by the force is

$\int_{s_0}^{s_1} F ds = m\int_{s_0}^{s_1} a \ ds$

Now, let's do a trick:

$m\int_{s_0}^{s_1} a \ ds = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} a \ dt \ \frac {ds}{dt} .$

But since $adt = dv$  and $ds/dt =v$ we get,

$\int_{s_0}^{s_1} F ds = m\int_{v_0}^{v_1} v \ dv = m\frac {v_1^2 - v_0^2}{2},$

where I changed the limits of integration in the integral in the middle because the variable of integration changed. Indeed the mechanical work in your problem increases the kinetic energy.

Comment: You might have proved the obvious equivalence of a • s and v • v, but I am looking for an intuitive description of energy using twice velocity instead of acceleration + distance.

Comment: Let me ask another way. Is it clear that applying a force to an object, its velocity would increase? And if yes, is your question why does it increase as $v^2$ and not simply $v$ is proportional to $F$ ?

Comment: Energy is proportional to squared velocity, rest energy is proportional to mass and function of squared speed of light - how can we imagine this? There seems to be no intuitive approach. Example: the damage caused by a forest fire in a day may be proportional to its squared speed. This is intuitionally comprehensible, in the same way as that work W is proportional to acceleration a and to distance s.

Answer (score 1):

I think of V^2 as the rate of change of the surface area of an expanding sphere , it's radius changing at constant V , but the surface area A = Pi r^2 expanding at v^2. Does that help ?

Also in:  E = MC^2

E = The total energy of a body **at rest**, V = 0

C^2 is a constant of proportionality, a real number, but not dimentionless - otherwise the formula would not be dimenionaly consistant. But this is beyond me!

Comment: Your first idea is very interesting and may be felt as the first half of the answer. But is there a concept of energy which could use this squared velocity (in connection with a mass factor)?