# Why is there a difference in Energy required to raise the velocity of an object by one unit when it is fast than when it is slow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

Why would i need more energy to raise the velocity of an object from 2 m/s to 3 m/s, than raising the velocity of the same object from 1 m/s to 2 m/s.
Note: I am not talking about the math related to this question, I am talking about the physical intuition. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/why-does-kinetic-energy-increase-quadratically-not-linearly-with-speed?rq=1

Comment: under application of a constant force, velocity grows proportionally to time of application, whereas energy grows proportionally to distance covered; the latter increases with increasing velocity

Answer (score -1):

Inertia in motion is more in first case is more than that in second case, so more energy is needed in first case.