# Kinetic energy in Lagragian mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, velocity, coordinate-systems

In my classical mechanics class they asked why the kinetic energy for an holonomic mechanical system has the homogeneous quadratic form. 
Of course for a autonomous standard system( system that is holonomic and the constraint do no virtual work) you can just calculate that 
$$
T = \frac { 1 } { 2 } \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { M } m _ { i } \left( v _ { i } \cdot v _ { i } \right) = \sum _ { j = 1 } ^ { n } \sum _ { k = 1 } ^ { n } a _ { j k } ( q ) \dot { q } _ { j } \dot { q } _ { k }
$$ with
$$
a _ { j k } ( \boldsymbol { q } ) = \frac { 1 } { 2 } \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { N } m _ { i } \left( \frac { \partial \boldsymbol { r } _ { i } } { \partial q _ { j } } \cdot \frac { \partial r _ { i } } { \partial q _ { k } } \right)
$$
So you can write
$$
T = \dot { q } ^ { T } \cdot A \cdot \dot { q }
$$
But what is the physical reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does kinetic energy increase quadratically, not linearly, with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the kinetic term $T(q,\dot{q},t)$ is a second-order polynomial in the [generalized velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $\dot{q}$ can be viewed as:

1. a consequence of

   - the [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) that the positions ${\bf r}_i(q,t)$ do not depend on the generalized velocities $\dot{q}$,
   - and that the non-relativistic kinetic energy is $T=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{m_i}{2}\dot{\bf r}_i^2$,

   as OP already suggested.
2. merely an ansatz or approximation, partially justified by the fact that the kinetic term should be bounded from below. (This ansatz is famously violated for [relativistic point particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics).)

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Section 1.6.