# What is the energy density of Lattice Confinement Fusion?

Tags: energy, fusion

For quite some time I've seen this [video explaining it](https://youtu.be/yJTi7cnZtYI) and this news/article that NASA [detected energy from lattice confinement fusion](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/space/science/lattice-confinement-fusion/) and it always made me quite curious about the actual veracity of these claims, because people started saying it was some kind of "cold fusion" (I'm probably being just **too skeptical** here).

In the video it says it needs quite rare materials, but in this [website](https://spectrum.ieee.org/lattice-confinement-fusion) (it could be just an website), it says that titanium can also be used to some extent.

Well, assuming that it works, what is the energy density of this type of "fusion battery"?

Comment: did you check  fore "energy density" in the publications given at the bottom of your second link? Thanks for bringing the topic to our attention.

Comment: @annav sorry for not responding for the past months, this question just disappeared from my mind. Anyway, in one of the papers it is said "A deuteron is composed of a proton and
neutron. In the current research, nuclear reactions are triggered in titanium or erbium metal lattices loaded
with the hydrogen isotope deuterium—at densities approaching 1023 ions/cm3", but I can't make heads of the proportion that this is, it just says that it is the doble of energy inside tokamak fusion reactors. I still can't tell if it is the total energy or the useful output.

Comment: In this link from 2013 there are claims of energy density https://phys.org/news/2013-05-rossi-e-cat-energy-density-higher.html  . Unfortunately it seems it has not been confirmed independently and is still a wishfull expectation?