# What does the square in kinetic energy formula imply?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, speed

I was wondering if the velocity squared imply that you need exceedingly more energy to gain speed. And if so, why is this a thing?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does kinetic energy increase quadratically, not linearly, with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/)