Why does accelerating an object require more energy at higher speeds if velocity is relative?
Consider a 1 kg mass in the following two scenarios:

The mass accelerates from 0 m/s to 1 m/s.
The mass accelerates from 1 m/s to 2 m/s.

The kinetic energy required for (1) is $ \frac{1}{2} \times 1^2 = \frac{1}{2} \text{J}$. For (2), the energy needed is $ \frac{1}{2} \times 2^2 - \frac{1}{2} \times 1^2 = \frac{3}{2} \, \text{J}$, which is greater than for (1). This suggests that accelerating from 1 m/s to 2 m/s requires more energy—and thus more fuel—than accelerating from 0 m/s to 1 m/s.
But this seems to contradict the principle that velocity is relative. If I can measure the fuel burned, it appears I could deduce an "absolute" velocity, which goes against the idea that motion is relative. Could you help explain this apparent contradiction?

If you are accelerating, then you can feel it (because there's a force), so you know you are the one accelerating.

So is it true that more fuel is required to accelerate from 1 m/s to 2 m/s than from 0 m/s to 1 m/s?

How are you accelerating the mass?   This makes a difference.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535/123208

This question is similar to: Does doubling speed require double the fuel or quadruple the fuel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You didn’t give the elapsed time for 1 an 2 .

“ But this seems to contradict the principle that velocity is relative”. Velocity, and thus KE, is frame dependent, but CHANGE in velocity, and thus $\Delta KE$ is not. Assuming constant applied net force the reason more fuel is needed is the displacement of the object is greater and thus the net work done on it is greater in (2) than (1).
